# python error on string format with "\n" exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)

Tags: json, python-3.x, string

i try to construct JSON with string that contains "\n" in it like this :

```
ver_str= 'Package ID: version_1234\nBuild\nnumber: 154\nBuilt\n'
proj_ver_str = 'Version_123'
comb = '{"r_content": {0}, "s_version": {1}}'.format(ver_str,proj_ver_str)
json_content = json.loads()
d =json.dumps(json_content )
```

getting this error:

```
 exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Dev/python/new_tester/simple_main.py", line 18, in <module>
    comb = '{"r_content": {0}, "s_version": {1}}'.format(ver_str,proj_ver_str)
KeyError: '"r_content"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error arises not because of newlines in your values, but because of `{` and `}` characters in your format string other than the placeholders `{0}` and `{1}`.  If you want to have an actual `{` or a `}` character in your string, double them.

Try replacing the line

```py
comb = '{"r_content": {0}, "s_version": {1}}'.format(ver_str,proj_ver_str)
```

with

```py
comb = '{{"r_content": {0}, "s_version": {1}}}'.format(ver_str,proj_ver_str)
```

However, this will give you a different error on the next line, `loads() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'`.  This is because you presumably forgot to pass `comb` to `json.loads()`.

Replacing `json.loads()` with `json.loads(comb)` gives you another error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 15 (char 14)`.  This tells you that you've given `json.loads` malformed JSON to parse.  If you `print` out the value of `comb`, you see the following:

```
{"r_content": Package ID: version_1234
Build
number: 154
Built
, "s_version": Version_123}
```

This isn't valid JSON, because the string values aren't surrounded by quotes.  So a JSON parsing error is to be expected.

At this point, let's take a look at what your code is doing and what you seem to want it to do.  It seems you want to construct a JSON string from your data, but your code puts together a JSON string from your data, parses it to a `dict` and then formats it back as a JSON string.

If you want to create a JSON string from your data, it's far simpler to create a `dict` with your values and use `json.dumps` on that:

```py
d = json.dumps({"r_content": ver_str, "s_version": proj_ver_str})
```

Comment: this is a problem because i need to combine 2 jsons into one 
each JSON contains dynamic variables. 
i don't what to do json.dumps which works and then load it to jsone.loads() combain the 2 jsons  and then back again to do json.dumps .

Comment: @user63898: your comment is very unclear.  For one thing you don't say exactly how to 'combine' your data.  I can guess at what that might mean but I could well be wrong.  However, if this relates to your followup question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65181589/), which you have now accepted an answer for, then I guess there's nothing further for me to do.