# Python json.dumps TypeError: Object of type 'set' is not JSON serializable , when trying convert from variable , working when hardcoded

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

i try to create JSON string from variables in python but I get strange behaver

this result good formating when i hardcode the pro object:

```
rev_= 'Package ID: bbbbb\nBuild\nnumber: 154\nBuilt\n'
s_ver_str_ = 'bbb.bbb.3.3.98'
result = json.dumps({"rev": rev_, "s_ver_str": s_ver_str_, "pro": {'message': 'no verstion found'}})
```

but this return error when i try to set the pro object into variable :

```
    rev_= 'Package ID: bbbbb\nBuild\nnumber: 154\nBuilt\n'
    s_ver_str_ = 'bbb.bbb.3.3.98'
    pro_ = "'message': 'no verstion found'"
    result = json.dumps({"rev":rev_,"s_ver_str":s_ver_str_,"pro": { pro_ }})
```

getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1434, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Dev/python/new_tester/simple_main.py", line 19, in <module>
    result = json.dumps({"rev":rev_,"s_ver_str":s_ver_str_,"pro": { pro_ }})
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\json\encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'set' is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: `"pro": { pro_ }` The `{}` around `pro_` turns it into a set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that your code doesn't do what you expect it to do.
the curly brackets in Python are used for both `dict` and `set` objects.

if you are using them like that:

```
{'message': 'Hello World'}
```

an object of type `dict` is created.

However, if you use them like that:

```
{'Hello World'}
```

an object of type `set` is created.

Your `pro` variable, is a single `str` variable, therefore, doing the following:

```
pro_ = {"'message': 'no verstion found'"}
```

would create a `set` with one value only - your string.

---

If you would like to serialize that set into the json, you can do it with `list(_pro)` but that wouldn't really make any sense, as it will also contain your quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

`pro_` is a string literal while you want it to be a dictionary like in your first example.

```
rev_= 'Package ID: bbbbb\nBuild\nnumber: 154\nBuilt\n'
s_ver_str_ = 'bbb.bbb.3.3.98'
pro_ = {"message": "no verstion found"}
result = json.dumps({"rev":rev_,"s_ver_str":s_ver_str_,"pro": pro_ })
```